# Есть Bootstrap код , не понимаю его назначение

Tags: html, bootstrap

Есть вот такой код

```
<main class="py-4">

</main>
```

Не понимаю назначение *класса* `py-3`, Если *это паддинг топ* то *почему не используется* класс  `pt-3` ?

В чем *разница* между `py-3` и `pt-3` ?

Если разница *только в  Bootstrap версии*, тогда **совместим ли с Bootstrap 4** класс `py-3` ?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/ Отступ от верха и низа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Читайте документацию bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)

В записи `py-4`:

- первая буква `p` - задает css свойство `padding` - внутренний отступ
- вторая буква `y` - добавляет к отступу `-top` и `-bottom`, тем самым указывая положение сверху и снизу
- `4` - задает значение отступа в `$spacer * 1.5`, т.е. просто число.

**Итого:**

`py-4` **⇒** `main { padding-top: 1.5rem; padding-bottom: 1.5rem; }`

---

**В чем разница?! :**

Внутренний отступ `padding` (в bootstrap4 это класс `p...`), как и внешний отступ `margin` (в bootstrap4 это класс `m...`), можно задавать для 4-х положений: `-top`, `-right`, `-bottom`, `-left`.

В bootstrap 4 все эти положения задаются первой буквой положения (в дополнение к 'p ...'):

`pt-4` - **⇒** `padding-top: 1.5rem;`
`pr-4` - **⇒** `padding-right: 1.5rem;`
`pb-4` - **⇒** `padding-bottom: 1.5rem;`
`pl-4` - **⇒** `padding-left: 1.5rem;`

---

Есть еще запись: `px-4`. В данном случае `x` - задает два отступа для левой стороны и правой.

Т.е. `px-4` **⇒** `main { padding-left: 1.5rem; padding-right: 1.5rem; }`

---

**P.S:**

Может быть так еще будет понятней:

- `py-3` это одновременно `pt-3` **и** `pb-3`,
- `px-3` это одновременно `pl-3` **и** `pr-3`.

Все аналогично и для внешнего отступа - `margin`.